# Ajax code from dynamic content doesn't execute

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a dynamic webpage created. Page contents come from a table in MySQL. Here is the content coming from database when a tab is clicked. Page has a table whose values are populated from an external JS file using the `<td>` id. Script is added after the page is rendered.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <div class=col-md-12>
            <table class="table table-striped  table-responsive table-hover" 
                   id="fp_table" style="display:none">
              <colgroup>
                <col class="col-md-1>
                <col class=" col-md-7>
              </colgroup>
              <tbody>
                <tr class="table-bordered">
                  <th id="val1_h" class="info-big col-md-1">Value 1</th>
                  <td id="val1" class="fp class=" fp col-md-7 "></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="table-bordered">
                  <th id="val2_h" class="info col-md-1">Value 2</th>
                  <td id="val2" class="fp col-md-7"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="table-bordered">
                  <th id="val3_h" class="info col-md-1">Value 3</th>
                  <td id="val3" class="fp class=" fp col-md-7 "></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="table-bordered">
                  <th id="val4_h" class="info col-md-1">Value 4</th>
                  <td id="val4" class="fp class=" fp col-md-7 "></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="table-bordered ">
                  <td id="val5_h" class="info col-md-1 ">Value 5</td>
                  <td id="val5" class="fp col-md-7 " 
                  style="word-wrap: break-word;min-width: 300px;max-width: 300px; "></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="table-bordered ">
                  <th id="val6_h" class="info col-md-1 ">Value 6</th>
                  <td id="val6" class="fp col-md-7 "></td>
                </tr>
                <tr  class="table-bordered ">
                  <th id="val7_h" class="info col-md-1 ">Value 7</th>
                  <td id="val7" class="fp col-md-7 "></td>
                <tr class="table-bordered ">
                  <th id="val8_h"class="info col-md-1 ">Value 8</th>
                  <td id="val8" class="fp col-md-7 table-bordered "></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="table-bordered ">
                  <th id="val9_h" class="info col-md-1 ">Value 9</th>
                  <td id="val9" class="fp col-md-7 "></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="table-bordered ">
                  <th id="val10_h" class="info col-md-1 ">Value 10</th>
                  <td id="val10" class="fp col-md-7 "></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="table-bordered ">
                  <th id="val11_h" class="info col-md-1 ">Value 11</th>
                  <td id="val11" class="fp col-md-7 "></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <div id="status"></div>
            </div>
        </div>      
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="btnFP" >
          Click to view hidden table
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/js_code_that_populates_table.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function insert_data() {
    var val1 = document.getElementById("val1").innerHTML;
    var val2 = document.getElementById("val2").innerHTML;
    var val3 = document.getElementById("val3").innerHTML;
    var val4 = document.getElementById("val4").innerHTML;
    var val5 = document.getElementById("val5").innerHTML;
    var val6 = document.getElementById("val6").innerHTML;
    var val7 = document.getElementById("val7").innerHTML;
    var val8 = document.getElementById("val8").innerHTML;
    var val9 = document.getElementById("val9").innerHTML;
    var val10 = document.getElementById("val10").innerHTML;
    var val11 = document.getElementById("val11").innerHTML;
    $( window ).on( "load", function() { 
        console.log('document ready');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "config/insert.php",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { sendval1:val1, sendval2:val2, sendval3:val3, 
                    sendval4:val4, sendval5:val5, sendval6:val6, 
                    sendval7:val7, sendval8:val8, sendval9:val9, 
                    sendval10:val10, sendval11:val11  },
            success: function(data){
               alert('Success');
            },
            error: function(req, err){ console.log('my message' + err); 
            }
        });
    });
}
insert_data();   
$( "button" ).click(function() {
    $( "table" ).toggle();
    $( "button" ).hide();
});
</script>
```

This is the PHP code that I have to insert into a second table in DB

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(0);

    include('../../config/connection.php');

    $storeval1 = $_POST['sendval1'];
    $storeval2 = $_POST['sendval2']; 
    $storeval3 = $_POST['sendval3'];
    $storeval4 = $_POST['sendval4'];
    $storeval5 = $_POST['sendval5'];
    $storeval6 = $_POST['sendval6'];
    $storeval7 = $_POST['sendval7'];
    $storeval8 = $_POST['sendval8'];
    $storeval9 = $_POST['sendval9'];
    $storeval10 = $_POST['sendval10'];
    $storeval11 = $_POST['sendval11'];


    $q1 = "SELECT * FROM storeData where col1 = '$storeval1'";
    $r1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q1); 
    $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($r1);

    if($rowcount == 1)
    {
       echo json_encode("Yes");
    } else {
      $q =INSERT INTO storeData(col1,col2,col3,col4,
             col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11) VALUES 
            ('$storeval1','$storeval2','$storeval3','$storeval4',
             '$storeval5','$storeval6','$storeval7','$storeval8',
             '$storeval9','$storeval10','$storeval11')";
      $r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);
      $rows = mysqli_num_rows($r);

    if($rows == 1) {
        echo json_encode("Record Added");
    }else {
        echo json_encode("Error adding");

    }       
}
?>
```

If I create a new PHP page with the table and AJAX code it inserts data on page load. But when the same code is populated when the HTML code and AJAX code comes from DB, it inserts a record 0 but not the actual values.

When I open the page I see `my messageparsererror` in Console. Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: my messageparsererror certainly means that there was a parse error somewhere ;) Could you check the source? I'm guessing that you are not sending a properly formatted JSON document.

Comment: Reading more carefully, I do not see any other problem, as you are sending innerHTML of the table cells which are all empty. So it is normal you are not saving anything. Is there suposed to be values there? Try a console.log of your data before you do the request, to see if it is JS or PHP fault

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: How do I check if the data being sent is properly formatted in JSON or not? Sorry if it is a dumb question, but a total beginner here trying to learn.

Comment: @salketer `console.log('sendval1...11')` shows proper HTML values that are taken from the  div's `innerHTML`

Comment: you can open your developper console (usually F12) on your browser and check the network tab. You will be able to see what you sent to the server and what you are receiving back.

Comment: For insert.php it doesn't show as form data instead shows as Request payload and all send values are concatenated
`sendval1=549615&sendval2=asdh192&sendval3=Chrome%2059&...`

Comment: @deathsmiles that's normal URLencoding and should be fine for the server to pick up.

Comment: Also when I check the preview tab for insert.php it shows Error

Comment: Adding `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"` to the AJAX call fixed it, but is this the right way to send? I know @MagnusEriksson mentioned its open to SQL Injection but the prepared statements seems a little over my head right now.

Comment: @deathsmiles If you're just getting started learning, I would recommend spending the time to use prepared statements from the start. Otherwise, you're learning, and writing, insecure code which still would need to be rewritten. It's not hard and you actually wouldn't need to change much in your current code.

Comment: I do not see the `newrow ` or `existingdata ` parameters passed back to the AJAX call. I would like to add the `success/failure` to a `<div>` after the page is loaded (newrow - if record doesnt exist in db and existingdata - if record already exist in db)

Comment: since your ajax expects JSON back, try `echo json_encode("success");`, and the same for the failure case. BTW what _do_ you see returned? Any content at all? Does it return HTTP 200 OK? Any errors in your console?

Comment: @ADyson That worked. Adding `echo json_encode("success");` shows the alert box with success . Thanks

Comment: @ADyson This is what insert.php headers show - http://imgur.com/a/G2XRx. How do I access the `newrow/existing` values sent back to the function. 
 `success: function(data){ if ((data.??) == 'newrow') { ("#status").html="New Row"}else {("#status").html="Existing"}` I know I am horribly wrong with that code but am I on the right path?

Comment: `success: function(data){ alert(data); }` should show "existing" or "newrow" as appropriate, because it'll just be a really basic object that's returned. If not, do `success: function(data){ alert(JSON.stringify(data)); }` and it'll show you the structure of the returned object, so you can work out how to access the values. Or you can look in the "Response" section of the request in the network tab.

Comment: @ADyson It shows Error in alert when I add `success: function(data){ alert(JSON.stringify(data)); `. Even after deleting the record in DB and loading the page it shows error, but data is getting inserted successfully into db

Comment: it just says "Error"? Or something more? What about in your browser's developer console? Any errors or messages there?

Comment: I modified the PHP code a little. When I delete the data from DB and run the page for the first time it shows `Error adding`. If I load the page again it says `Data Exist`

Comment: Used mysqli_affected_rows() in if condition. Worked now. Thanks for the guidance @Adyson,  Magnus Eriksson & Salketer